# spring batch with multiple data sources requiring default transactionManager bean

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-batch

I am using spring batch to read from one db and load into another db. If I name the transaction managers with the primary not set to "transactionManager" then I get the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value
>   [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@355c94be] for
>   key
>   [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@2c532cd8]
>   bound to thread [main]

To get around this, I have to have name the primary db config as "transactionManager". Is there a way to use the name I want?

First do config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "db1EntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "db1TransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"com.foo.bar.car.repository.db1"})
    public class Db1Config {
       .
       .
       .

        @Primary
        @Bean
        public PlatformTransactionManager db1TransactionManager() {

            JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
            transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(db1EntityManager().getObject());
            return transactionManager;
        }
```

2nd db config

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "db2EntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "db2TransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"com.foo.bar.car.repository.db2"})
    public class Db2Config {
       .
       .
       .
    // no primary annotation
        @Bean
        public PlatformTransactionManager db2TransactionManager() {

            JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
            transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(db2EntityManager().getObject());
            return transactionManager;
        }
```

Comment: did you resolve this issue?